# ERROR "mpirun: Forwarding signal 18 to job"

Tags: bash, mpi

I am running a code which uses:

- openmpi-4.0.3_gcc-7.1
- Trilinos-14
- boost_1_81_0
- lapack-3.11

after more or less an hour of computations, I always get the error:

mpirun: Forwarding signal 18 to job

I am sure that computations are not stalling or facing particular convergence problems.

Everything is installed and configured as my colleagues in bashrc, but I am the only one with this error.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I forgot to say that there are no memory leaks, that memory is well distributed and not fragmented.

Comment: For some reason, `mpirun` received `SIGCONT`. Is this something you expect?

Comment: Honestly speaking, not. And I do not know from where it may come from.

Comment: Are you running under a resource manager such as LSF?

Comment: No, my resource manager is slurm.